# Iteration over an array of elements with a separate delay

Tags: javascript

I'm strugguling with javascript setTimeout that holds an iteration over an array. I am trying to achieve that on click the function will go over each element of the array and execute it at a slightly different time - with the clicked item being the last.

```
function hide(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0
  el.classList.remove("fade-up-out")
  el.style.pointerEvents = "none"
}

function fadeAllOut(elArray) {
  elArray.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.add("fade-up-out")
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    elArray.forEach(hide)
  }, FADEDURATION)
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need? Specifically, would using [async functions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions) be okay?

Comment: Chrome would be the preferred choice, but how would I do it with async?

Answer (score 1):

An async function can do this in a natural way by pausing itself and letting `setTimeout` resume it by resolving a promise.

A function to create a promise that resolves after a timeout:

```
const delay = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
```

A function to fade one element out:

```
const fadeOutAndHide = el => {
  el.classList.add("fade-up-out")
  setTimeout(hide, FADEDURATION, el)
}
```

The loop:

```
const fadeOutInSequence = async elArray => {
  for (const el of elArray) {
    fadeOutAndHide(el)
    await delay(/* some amount of time */)
  }
}
```

Or, if an element should start fading out immediately after the previous one is hidden, the middle function isn’t necessary:

```
const fadeOutInSequence = async elArray => {
  for (const el of elArray) {
    el.classList.add("fade-up-out")
    await delay(FADEDURATION)
    hide(el)
  }
}
```

(You might also want to look into achieving this with [transition events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) instead.)

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` delays the execution of a single call, so you need to call it once per element if you want to give a separate delay to each.

```
function fadeAllOut(elArray, delayBetween) {
  let timeout = 0;
  elArray.forEach(function (el) {
    el.classList.add("fade-up-out");
    setTimeout(() => hide(el), timeout);
    timeout += delayBetween;
  });
}
```

If you want to apply a delay even to the first element, change the initialisation to `let timeout = delayBetween;` instead.

Then you can call `fadeAllOut(elements, 500)` and it will fade out the elements one by one with a 0.5s interval between each.

If you want to apply the fadeout effect to all elements of a list in a random order with the selected item last, simply shuffle the array before passing it to the function.

```
fadeAllOut([...shuffle(otherElements), selectedElement], 500);
```

You can find efficient shuffle algorithms pretty much everywhere.

Here's a working example you can try, which I've slightly altered based on how I would implement it from the CSS side.

```js
const shuffleArray = arr => arr
  .map(a => [Math.random(), a])
  .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
  .map(a => a[1]);

function fadeOutBegin(el) {
  el.classList.add("fade-out-begin");
  el.disabled = true;
}

function fadeOutEnd(el) {
  el.classList.remove("fade-out-begin");
  el.classList.add("fade-out-end");
}

function fadeAllOut(elArray, delayBetween) {
  let timeout = 0;
  elArray.forEach(function (el) {
    fadeOutBegin(el);
    setTimeout(() => fadeOutEnd(el), timeout);
    timeout += delayBetween;
  });
}

let fruitButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
fruitButtons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
  let unselected = new Set(fruitButtons);
  unselected.delete(el);
  
  fadeAllOut([...shuffleArray([...unselected]), el], 250);
}));
```

```css
button {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.fade-out-begin {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-out-end {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Apple</button><br>
<button>Banana</button><br>
<button>Cherry</button><br>
<button>Durian</button><br>
<button>Eggplant</button><br>
<button>Fig</button><br>
<button>Grape</button><br>
```

Comment: The error I seem to be getting is that setTimout is not deffined. Why would that be?

Comment: Might want to type `setTimeout` and not `setTimout` for a start ;)
Though I haven't tested that code yet so I might have made typos myself.

Comment: Yep, I put a capital letter for no reason on the O. I fixed it. Though there seems to be something else wrong with my code if "fade-up-out" is the class which makes something fade out.

Comment: yes, "fade-up-out" is a class for a css animation and it doesn't delay things in between... so if let timeOut = 0, then the first element gets delayed but not the others. When I change it to equal delayBetween they all fade at the same time

Comment: See this for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/nq3h8cvs/
I'll add that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try setInterval instead:

```
function iterate(){
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        hide(elArray[i++]);
        if(i == elArray.length) clearInterval(interval);
    }, FADEDURATION);
}
```